# Securely send data from iOS to Server

Tags: ios, swift, security, sha256, credit-card

I am looking to send credit card information from my iOS app to my server. What is the best way to get this done securely?

Information would include: Name, Credit Card Number, Expiration Date, and the CVV.

Would a base64 string be good enough? or should I use some sort of encryption. If so how do i go about setting that up?

Comment: Base64 is not viable solution as it is easily decoded. Use https secure connection at the very least. It begs the question of how secure your server is, though. How are you authenticating users? How have you secured your database? Etc. There’s a lot more than just securing the POST of the data. We’re not going to be able to do justice to the broad array of security issues here. You’re going to want to get a security expert review this, soup to nuts, before you start storing such sensitive data. Perhaps you consider PassKit/Apple Pay rather than storing payment info yourself.

Comment: For intro to PassKit, see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit). For general introductions to security issues, see Apple’s [Security](https://developer.apple.com/security/) page, which includes links to their various Crypto libraries, amongst other things.